# CherryPy on OpenShift not updating

Tags: openshift, cherrypy

I following the instructions in https://www.openshift.com/quickstarts/cherrypy and deployed the sample application successfully.

I made some changes to the wsgi/application file and push the changes. When i ssh in to take a look the changes were made to the application file but when i refresh my page, i still see the old page.

All i did was to change "Hello World!" to "Hello" in wsgi/application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Openshift updated the way they do things March 14.  Some of the docs and quickstarts are out of date.

I have only used the wsgi server in Cherrypy and not the whole framework itself but the below info may help.  You want to place a file called 'app.py' in your root openshift directory.  This is the 'entry point' for starting your application.  There is also a 'wsgi.py' entry point but I don't think you want that.  Take a look at the bug report I posted below to learn more about it.

Here is my app.py

```
import os
from myapp import my_app
from cherrypy import wsgiserver

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
    app = my_app(global_config=None)

    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer((ip, port), app, server_name='myapp Server')
    server.start()
```

You might also want to look at this bug here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1082363

HTH